# ShellExecuteEx can't open image while mspaint is default app since windows 10

Tags: c++, windows-10

The execution of the following code will give an error if **mspaint** is chosen as the default app for images.

Setting default app for images to any other app, e.g. "Photos", will open the image with the chosen app without error.

Using `ShExecInfo.lpVerb = L"edit"` will open the image with mspaint without error.

The problem occurs since Windows 10.

```
#include <shlwapi.h>

int main()
{
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo;
    ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    ShExecInfo.fMask = NULL;
    ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
    ShExecInfo.lpVerb = L"open"; //L"edit"
    ShExecInfo.lpFile = L"C:/test.jpg";
    ShExecInfo.lpParameters = NULL;
    ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
    ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_MAXIMIZE;
    ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;

    ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Is it a known Microsoft bug?

Comment: @AdrianMole jep. As I wrote, it opens it also with ```ShellExecuteEx``` setting ```lpVerb``` to ```L"edit"```

Comment: What happens if you run `start C:\test.jpg` at a cmd prompt?

Comment: @dvix just tested: the file opens with mspaint.

Comment: Try passing `NULL` for `ShExecInfo.lpVerb` to use the default verb. Looking at `HKCR\Applications\mspaint.exe\shell` it seems `MSPaint` does not register the `"open"` verb.

Comment: @dxiv, jep, there are workarounds for the issue and it works the way you suggested with ```ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL``` ( I suppose it is mapped to ```edit``` in that case). But I still need ```ShExecInfo.lpVerb = L"open"``` due to business reasons.

Comment: Guess you could register an `"open"` verb under `mspaint`'s name by copying the `"edit"` key. That would mean hardcoding an exception for `mspaint` specifically, but the other option would be to petition Microsoft to add it and hope they listen. A more general approach could be to check that the `"open"` verb is actually registered before attempting to use it. Not sure what the "*business logic*" would have you do if it turns out that `"open"` is *not* registered.

Comment: @dxiv, nope, just played around with ```HKCR\Applications\mspaint.exe\shell``` regkeys and it doesn't change the behavior of the program. Seems there are other regkeys used by ```ShellExecuteEx```. But thank you for the idea.

Comment: `NULL` is the way to to for `lpVerb`.  As [per MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea) for `NULL`: `The default verb is used, if available. If not, the "open" verb is used. If neither verb is available, the system uses the first verb listed in the registry.`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFOW ShExecInfo = {};
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFOW);
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = L"edit";
ShExecInfo.lpFile = L"C:/test.jpg";
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_MAXIMIZE;
ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOASYNC;

if (!ShellExecuteExW(&ShExecInfo))
{
    // Error reported in GetLastError()
```

- There's no `open` verb associated with JPEG's in this case. Either leave `lpVerb` as null or set it to `edit`.
- You need to use `SEE_MASK_NOASYNC` since your example has no Win32 message loop.

> You also likely want to add `SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI` to avoid that message box in case of errors so your program can handle them instead.